# SAS: Date intervals into columns

Tags: date, sas

I want to do something in SAS that I am struggling to put into words.

Basically, I have a list of hotels with dates of stays - see table one.
I want to change the table so that I have a list of nights stayed - see table two.

My first table has two fields reflecting when a customer arrives and second field reflecting when a customer leaves a hotel. The second table the date fields lists the nights stayed at the hotel. I say nights as the second date is the date they leave the hotel so they wont stay the night.

How do I get from table one to table two?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dates are stored as numbers, it's a pretty straightforward task to just loop from the in_date to the day before the out_date and output each iteration of the loop.

```
data have;
infile datalines dsd;
input hotel $ customer_name $ City $ in_date :date9. out_date :date9.;
format in_date out_date date9.;
datalines;
Hotel A, Joe, New York, 01jan2015, 04jan2015
Hotel B, Joe, Chicago, 05feb2015, 07feb2015
Hotel C, Sam, Portland, 15jun2015, 18jun2015
Hotel D, Amy, Boston, 04mar2015, 07mar2015
Hotel C, Sam, Portland, 15oct2015, 17oct2015
Hotel A, Tom, New York, 01nov2015, 02nov2015
;
run;

data want;
set have;
format stay_date date9.;
do stay_date = in_date to out_date-1;
output;
end;
drop in_date out_date;
run;
```

Comment: Keith thanks for the code. My question may in hindsight prove a daft one, but your code includes the table of data.  My data set is obviously larger, how would use my data table in the data step you provided?  A from my data doesn't work.  Thanks for your help. Paul

Comment: Just reference it in the `set` statement

Answer (score -1):

To calc count of nights you should to this code^

```
data table_one;
   set table_one;
   count_nights = out_date - in_date;
run;
```

To add this calculated attribute to `table_two` try this code:

Ex. 1:

```
data table_two;
   merge table_two table_one;
   by hotel, customer_name, city;
run;
```

Ex. 2:

Also you can calc count of nigths from `table_two` as

```
proc sql;
   create table table_two_nights as
   select t.*, count(*) as count_nights
   from table_two
   group by hotel, customer_name, city;
quit;
```

Comment: In Ex1 you can't have comma's between your variables in the BY statement. This also doesn't answer the question.